Are these verses about Hashem's anger a contradiction?
In Micah 7:18, it is written:

מִי־אֵ֣ל כָּמ֗וֹךָ נֹשֵׂ֤א עָוֺן֙ וְעֹבֵ֣ר עַל־פֶּ֔שַׁע לִשְׁאֵרִ֖ית נַחֲלָת֑וֹ לֹֽא־הֶחֱזִ֤יק לָעַד֙ אַפּ֔וֹ כִּֽי־חָפֵ֥ץ חֶ֖סֶד הֽוּא׃
Who is a God like You,
Forgiving iniquity
And remitting transgression—
Not staying angry forever
Toward the remnant of Your own people,
Because You love graciousness!

But in Jeremiah 17:4 it states:

וְשָׁמַטְתָּ֗ה וּבְךָ֙ מִנַּחֲלָֽתְךָ֙ אֲשֶׁ֣ר נָתַ֣תִּי לָ֔ךְ וְהַעֲבַדְתִּ֙יךָ֙ אֶת־אֹ֣יְבֶ֔יךָ בָּאָ֖רֶץ אֲשֶׁ֣ר לֹא־יָדָ֑עְתָּ כִּֽי־אֵ֛שׁ קְדַחְתֶּ֥ם בְּאַפִּ֖י עַד־עוֹלָ֥ם תּוּקָֽד׃ {ס}
You will forfeit, by your own act,
The inheritance I have given you;
I will make you a slave to your enemies
In a land you have never known.
For you have kindled the flame of My wrath
That shall burn for all time.

In one place it says Hashem is being praised for not staying angry forever but in another it says that the flame of anger will burn for all of time.

Note that עד עולם doesn't always mean "forever." In the vast majority of pesukim it does, but a counterexample is Shmuel 1:1:22.

Note that the first set are attributes of mercy/compassion (Rachamim). Rachamim overcomes anger (Gevura).

@RabbiKaii Sure, I guess my question made simpler would be: We know that Hashem has rachamim, so what does it mean in Jeremiah that Hashem's wrath will burn for all time?

עד־עולם is a finite period of time, until the end of this era. The next one begins with the arrival of Mashiakh. If it had said לעולם ועד, it WOULD mean forever.

@Seeker "what does it mean in Jeremiah that Hashem's wrath will burn for all time"? It means Gevura. If Rachamim limits Gevura, doesn't that imply that Gevura is otherwise less limited? Are you assuming that Rachamim will always limit Gevura? You haven't shown why you would assume that.

@QwertyCTRL. i can accept that point if there is a source for that rather than a personal interpretation, because for me עד־עולם means until forever which is forever. Perhaps I should open a new question as to the meaning of the phrase.

@RabbiKaii Correct me if I'm wrong but that kind of sounds like you're proving my point. If it is not limited by rachamim then it truly can last forever which would mean that it's in contradiction with the statement in Micah.

@Seeker yes you are wrong but I'm not sure how to correct. I can't think of how to explain it any other way. "If you do this, it will never stop being angry, unless you apologize and invoke my compassion" is not a contradiction. It's a condition

@RabbiKaii I actually agree that Hashem's "anger" can be tamed. However, in order for the contradiction to be cleared you would have to say 1) that the verse in Micah means that the anger will only wane if teshuva is done and 2) the verse in Jeremiah only means that it will last forever if you do not do teshuva. This is a valid response as long as there's a source for that.

@Seeker the fact that these are 13 middot of Rachamim already implies that Rachamim overcomes Gevura. Would simply bringing the sources that they are Rachamim suffice? I'm not sure why you need a source that Rachamim can overcome Gevura (even though it's implied in the very verses you bring) otherwise. Those can be easily found though

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The Ahavat Yehonatan (on the Haftarah of Behar) explains that "forever" overhere means fifty years, as we find by a Jewish slave who goes free after the fiftieth year, even though it says that he is to be a slave "forever", and these fifty years are referring to what the Talmud And Midrash  say, that there were fifty years during which not even a bird flew over the land of Israel.

Why does it use the words "עַד־עוֹלָ֥ם" though? More dramatic?

@Seeker I didn't see this in a source, but that literally translates as "until Olam". Curious

Hashem is saying in Yirmiyahu "If you do that unacceptable thing, I will never stop being angry at you".
Hashem is saying in Micha "but if you say sorry and mean it, I can and will stop being angry".

The list in Micha is a list of middot of Rachamim. Rachamim is the attribute/perfection in Hashem that feels compassionate towards His creations, which overcomes His anger towards them, which comes from Gevura - His attribute of judgement and justice.
This Rabbeinu Bachaye is a great resource in understanding this classic Torah concept, i.e. that Hashem is compassionate and therefore we can find a route out of His anger towards us - which should be eternal - and gain forgiveness and reconciliation through Tefilla and Teshuva.
The piece brings the Midrash that when Moshe first met Hashem on Sinai, he found Him putting crowns on the letters. Eventually Hashem said to Moshe "how come you didn't greet me when you saw me? Do people not do that where you come from?", and Moshe said "it is not permitted for a slave to greet his Master". Hashem's response was shocking: "I need you to help Me".
To do something as minor as failing to greet Hashem, the Supreme Master, King of Kings, Perfect, Eternal and Righteous, fitting of all conceivable praises and more... is a grave offense, not to mention the far more serious sins discussed in Yirmiyahu. Therefore it is only fitting that His response to such an offense is anger that is as infinite and eternal as Him.
Yet, He doesn't want to be angry at us forever. He started this project, and He wants us. Therefore, He teaches Moshe what is the proper way to be in a relationship with Him, and He teaches Moshe about His trait of Rachamim. The piece goes into a lot of detail on what Hashem taught Moshe, in the sense of "When you make me angry, I need your help so that I won't be angry forever, so I am going to teach you about Myself, and what you need to do to evoke My Compassion for you at such times".
For example, with the sin of the spies, invoking His trait of נוצר חסד לאלפים, i.e. the way He remembers the zechut of our forefathers and forgives us on their behalf, would have been inappropriate because the sin specifically was contempt for the land that the forefathers held dear and stood for. All Moshe was able to do is invoke the very trait you are asking about - slow to anger. This means that instead of wiping us out, He spreads the punishment out over many generations, so each gets only a little, bearable amount.
This conforms with our thesis because indeed, this is the trait Moshe invoked because the people had not done Teshuva. In such a case, Moshe can't really expect Hashem to not be angry forever - exactly as Yirmiyahu said! So he asked Hashem to spread out the anger, and also add some more merit due to His trait of רב חסד, as well as His trait of forgiving even rebellious sins, and of not punishing immediately but seeing up to the third or fourth generation if any of the kids or grandkids will to Teshuva. Otherwise, even Moshe admits that He is לא ינקה - He doesn't completely forgive those who do not do Teshuva.
We can relate to this to some degree. There are some things that our most beloved and important people in our lives can do, that would upset us so much that we would find it impossible to get over it, unless they sincerely apologise and change. And indeed we see that when they do sincerely apologise and change, we find the strength to forgive them and get over it! We even learn to trust them completely again.
We also can't relate to it, because Hashem's forgiveness is not like ours - when He forgives, He forgives completely as if it never happened, a trait He did not give over to mankind...
tl;dr: there's no contradiction at all. The very pesukim themselves imply that due to His Gevura, when Hashem is angry about certain things, He is angry עַד־עוֹלָם, and unless His Rachamim is invoked, indeed His anger would last forever ch'v. The first pasuk is explaining what our invoking His Rachamim accomplishes (through Tefilla and/or Teshuva) vis-à-vis the second pasuk; His Gevura.

So, in Yirmiyah Hashem is saying that if you abandon Him - He will be angry forever but this can be fixed with teshuva as stated in Micah. The only thing is that it feels like we are kind of filling in blanks here - which can very well be correct but its just not stated. Also, lets say one never does teshuva - wouldn't they be punished in gehinnom and that would appease Hashem's anger? We know that a Jew can never go there for more than 12 months so the anger must be appeased through the punishment i.e. even without teshuva Hashem's anger wouldnt be forever. Unless it means kares?

@Seeker There's nothing wrong with filling in blanks as we don't put the burden on Hashem to repeat Himself, especially with regards to listing out conditions to statements made elsewhere. Your second statement about Gehinon etc is hard to answer here because it's really a separate question. If you ask it, I will try to answer it too, bli neder.
